# Android Market filter

Tags: android-manifest

I've a very specific question regarding Android Market device filtering.

Suppose that I want my application to be visible on Android vesrion 2.2, 2.3 and 4.0.

I want to exclude all tablets devices during device filtering on Android Market.

How can I achieve this?

Thanks,
Sushil

Answer (score 0):

When you upload your APK you can be as specific as you want.
You may specify the version aswell as what devices will be supported, i am unsure whether it is possible to exclude tablets, you might have to exclude them manually one by one in the device list.

This feature has been added to the market a while ago.